# Region Growing in Modelbuilder with Expand - while loop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, iterator

I have a series of points (farms) for which I am trying to grow differently sized territories based on the quality of land. I've set up a model where I expand each farm by one cell, then run zonal statistics, then a conditional tool whereby if the maximum value has been reached, then the region is 0, otherwise it is 1. This feeds into a While iterator which will run whilst there are still true values in the Conditional output. The expanded raster then feeds back to grow again.

[image]

The model iterates and grows the regions, however the "While" doesn't seem to be working. I.e. it continues to grow regions beyond the maximum value I set, and runs indefinitely. I'm obviously doing something wrong with my While iterator, but I can't see what. I've tried feeding back the conditional output that the While is based on, but that also runs indefinitely.

I've realised that the While iterator needs to have a Boolean input, so, despite the Con tool producing 0,1, I've switched out that process and replaced it with "Test" and it still won't stop at maximum.

Comment: I think it would be much easier to build this logic into a Python script using ArcPy.